# How to shift messages from queue to another queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ queue.

How to shift all messages from this queue after specific time (5 minutes) to another queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  I recommend setting a time to live on your messages and configuring the queue with a dead letter exchange and dead letter routing key.  Documentation for dead lettering can be found here:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html